# Dell: How can I figure out the "serial number" for monitors/accessories? (Not Service Tag)

Tags: api, serialization, serial-number

In a situation where my client's offices have emost of their monitors positioned against a flat surface or akwkardly placed where I cannot easily take a snapshot of the serial number as requested from time to time by tech support.  Serial numbers have a format such as CN-XXX-XXXXX-XXXXX and located next to serial tag on accessories.

FYI for clarity: the serial number is a unique identifier assigned by the manufacturer to each individual product. It is used to track the product throughout its life cycle, from production to sale and beyond. Just want to make this oft confused distinction.

I thought there would be a readily available script, or in the least within the portal of invoices there would contain documentation of the serial number.. Alas, there has not been.